# Canvas export to png does not export backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to export my final render of canvas everything works just fine exception when i set an SVG backgroundImage is completely ignored on export.

This is how i set the background image

```
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = true;
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svg, function (objects, options) {        
    var group = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    group.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        scaleY: 1.2,
        scaleX: 1.2,
        fill : front_color
    });
    //canvas.add(group);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(group, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
        backgroundImageStretch: true,
        color: front_color,
        repeat: 'repeat'
    });
    canvas.setBackgroundColor(fill_color);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

and this is how i export everything

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
```

Comment: you could try to export it as a jpeg?! `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);`

Comment: Same issue with jpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works fine for me in Chrome & Firefox, but fails in Internet Explorer.

Chrome and Firefox are fine with exporting SVG drawings on the canvas.

Internet Explorer will turn off `canvas.toDataURL` if you draw SVG to the canvas.

This is for security reasons--to prevent stealing user's info by exporting their secret info drawn on a canvas. This restriction may be lifted in new version of IE, but for now in IE you can't draw SVG to the canvas and then export the canvas with `.toDataURL`.

**The simplest workaround** is to convert your SVG background into .png or .jpg format. Internet Explorer will allow `.toDataURL` if the background image is in those formats.

**[ Addition per comment about resolution ]**

Webpage images (& everything on the page viewport) are always denoted in pixels.

If you want to export the canvas for printing (which needs a higher pixel count than your on-screen canvas) then you can use FabricJS's `toDataURLWithMultiplier` method which  increases the amount of pixels on the exported dataURL. It works by taking a single pixel and creating a 2x2 set of the same pixel (or 3x3, etc). Link about `toDataURLWithMultiplier`: 
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html.

That would let you substitute a larger .png image for your SVG image. As noted previously, using .png instead of SVG is currently the best cross-browser solution. ;-)

Comment: Have you chosen a background and worked when you saved?

Comment: I assumed the thermometer-with-tickmarks thingy was the background. Ok...retrying...done. Now Chrome succeeds. FF shows the thermometer but not the background. IE shows nothing. Have you tried converting your background SVG to .png format and using the .png image as the background?

Comment: I cannot convert it :( as you probably noted i need the end result to be at least 150dpi

Comment: DPI is a printing resolution and has nothing to do with image resolution on the canvas. I've added to my answer with information about exporting the canvas for printing.